# Configure action Handler with another class in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I try to make custom Control same as AlertController.

I want to add function as **Action Handler** same as AlertController.

**ViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction func showcustomAlert(){
        let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let CustomAlertController = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomAlertController") as! CustomAlertViewController
        CustomAlertController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

        CustomAlertController.addOKaction  = { print("done")} //Main issue
        self.present(CustomAlertController, animated: true) {

        }
    }
```

**CustomAlertController.swift**

```
@IBAction func OkPressed(){

}
```

How to define hander in customAlertController, so when "okPressed" called, it will print "done"??

How can I achieve this?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you please add some code that explains at least what you are trying to achieve? From this post it's really hard to understand what you're asking

Comment: Did you mean you want to add custom buttons like OK, cancel etc ?

Comment: @Sneha, yes exactly same

Comment: @nirav your approach is wrong.

Comment: @agent_stack, can you help to correct me?

Comment: this might be interesting for you: https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observing your code I assume that you have defined closer in your CustomAlertController class

like-

```
var addOKaction : (() -> ())?
```

and you did everything right just u have to call that closer when your ok button get pressed.

like-

```
@IBAction func OkPressed(){
 self.addOKaction()
}
```

and you will get callback when ok button will get pressed.

Comment: hello, I am checking 
Thank you...